# Multiple Dropdown Menu Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

We do not have a lot of experience with HTML or java script, what was built here, was created from other people's responses and code. So we are learning as we go.

But now we need a javascript function that will give us a URL specific to the items they choose on the drop down selections. We would need a different URL for each possible combination.

We have the products set up, we just need an interface for them to navigate easier.

You can see where we are right now with this link https://jsfiddle.net/christianxpinon/44jj3ata/

The site we are trying to load it on is crave-pop.squarespace.com

```
<form action="#" class="cascadeTest">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Tin Size:</th>
            <td>
                <select name="sizSelect" class="sizSelect">
                    <option value="0">Select an Tin Size</option>
                    <option value="1">2 Gallon</option>
                    <option value="2">3.5 Gallon</option>
                    <option value="3">6 Gallon</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Amount of Flavors:</th>
            <td>
                <select name="amtSelect" class="amtSelect">
                    <option value="0" class="static">- Amount of Flavors -</option>
                    <option value="1" class="sub_1">1 Flavor</option>
                    <option value="2" class="sub_1">2 Flavors</option>
                    <option value="3" class="sub_1">3 Flavors</option>
                    <option value="4" class="sub_2">1 Flavor</option>
                    <option value="5" class="sub_2">2 Flavors</option>
                    <option value="6" class="sub_2">3 Flavors</option>
                    <option value="7" class="sub_3">1 Flavor</option>
                    <option value="8" class="sub_3">2 Flavors</option>
                    <option value="9" class="sub_3">3 Flavors</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Flavor 1:</th>
            <td>
                <select name="flaSelect" class="flaSelect">
                    <option value="0" class="static">- All Flavors -</option>
                    <option value="1" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Old Fashion Butter</option>
                    <option value="2" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Naked Low Salt</option>
                    <option value="3" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Movie Theater</option>
                    <option value="4" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Cheddar Cheese</option>
                    <option value="5" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Jalapeno Cheddar</option>
                    <option value="6" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">White Cheddar</option>
                    <option value="7" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">White Cheddar & Bacon</option>
                    <option value="8" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Vinegar N Sea Salt</option>
                    <option value="9" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Dill Pickle</option>
                    <option value="10" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Simply Ranch</option>
                    <option value="12" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Ranch With A Kick</option>
                    <option value="13" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Cracked Black Pepper</option>
                    <option value="14" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Kettle</option>
                    <option value="15" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Classic Caramel</option>
                    <option value="16" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Pure Vanilla</option>
                    <option value="17" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">NYC Cheesecake</option>
                    <option value="18" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Roy G Biv</option>
                    <option value="19" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Dallas</option>
                    <option value="20" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Denver</option>
                    <option value="21" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Chicago</option>
                    <option value="22" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Team Spirit</option>
                    <option value="23" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Chocolate N Sea Salt</option>
                    <option value="24" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Cinnamon Bun</option>
                    <option value="25" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Dark Chocolate Toffee</option>
                    <option value="26" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Pecan Pie</option>
                    <option value="27" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Zebra</option>
                    <option value="28" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Puppy Chow</option>
                    <option value="29" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">White Chocolate Oreo</option>
                    <option value="30" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Nutella</option>
                    <option value="31" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Salted Nutty Caramel</option>
                    <option value="32" class="sub_1 or sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_4 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_7 or sub_8 or sub_9">Team Kelly</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Flavor 2:</th>
            <td>
                <select name="fla2Select" class="fla2Select">
                    <option value="0" class="static">- All Flavors -</option>
                    <option value="1" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Old Fashion Butter</option>
                    <option value="2" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Naked Low Salt</option>
                    <option value="3" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Movie Theater</option>
                    <option value="4" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Cheddar Cheese</option>
                    <option value="5" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Jalapeno Cheddar</option>
                    <option value="6" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">White Cheddar</option>
                    <option value="7" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">White Cheddar & Bacon</option>
                    <option value="8" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Vinegar N Sea Salt</option>
                    <option value="9" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Dill Pickle</option>
                    <option value="10" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Simply Ranch</option>
                    <option value="12" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Ranch With A Kick</option>
                    <option value="13" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Cracked Black Pepper</option>
                    <option value="14" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Kettle</option>
                    <option value="15" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Classic Caramel</option>
                    <option value="16" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Pure Vanilla</option>
                    <option value="17" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">NYC Cheesecake</option>
                    <option value="18" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Roy G Biv</option>
                    <option value="19" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Dallas</option>
                    <option value="20" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Denver</option>
                    <option value="21" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Chicago</option>
                    <option value="22" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Team Spirit</option>
                    <option value="23" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Chocolate N Sea Salt</option>
                    <option value="24" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Cinnamon Bun</option>
                    <option value="25" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Dark Chocolate Toffee</option>
                    <option value="26" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Pecan Pie</option>
                    <option value="27" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Zebra</option>
                    <option value="28" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Puppy Chow</option>
                    <option value="29" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">White Chocolate Oreo</option>
                    <option value="30" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Nutella</option>
                    <option value="31" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Salted Nutty Caramel</option>
                    <option value="32" class="sub_2 or sub_3 or sub_5 or sub_6 or sub_8 or sub_9">Team Kelly</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Flavor 3:</th>
            <td>
                <select name="fla3Select" class="fla3Select">
                    <option value="0" class="static">- All Flavors -</option>
                    <option value="1" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Old Fashion Butter</option>
                    <option value="2" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Naked Low Salt</option>
                    <option value="3" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Movie Theater</option>
                    <option value="4" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Cheddar Cheese</option>
                    <option value="5" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Jalapeno Cheddar</option>
                    <option value="6" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">White Cheddar</option>
                    <option value="7" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">White Cheddar & Bacon</option>
                    <option value="8" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Vinegar N Sea Salt</option>
                    <option value="9" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Dill Pickle</option>
                    <option value="10" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Simply Ranch</option>
                    <option value="12" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Ranch With A Kick</option>
                    <option value="13" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Cracked Black Pepper</option>
                    <option value="14" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Kettle</option>
                    <option value="15" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Classic Caramel</option>
                    <option value="16" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Pure Vanilla</option>
                    <option value="17" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">NYC Cheesecake</option>
                    <option value="18" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Roy G Biv</option>
                    <option value="19" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Dallas</option>
                    <option value="20" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Denver</option>
                    <option value="21" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Chicago</option>
                    <option value="22" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Team Spirit</option>
                    <option value="23" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Chocolate N Sea Salt</option>
                    <option value="24" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Cinnamon Bun</option>
                    <option value="25" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Dark Chocolate Toffee</option>
                    <option value="26" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Pecan Pie</option>
                    <option value="27" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Zebra</option>
                    <option value="28" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Puppy Chow</option>
                    <option value="29" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">White Chocolate Oreo</option>
                    <option value="30" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Nutella</option>
                    <option value="31" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Salted Nutty Caramel</option>
                    <option value="32" class="sub_3 or sub_6 or sub_9">Team Kelly</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Thank you in advance!

```
function cascadeSelect(parent, child){
            var childOptions = child.find('option:not(.static)');
                child.data('options',childOptions);

            parent.change(function(){
                childOptions.remove();
                child
                    .append(child.data('options').filter('.sub_' + this.value))
                    .change();
            })

            childOptions.not('.static, .sub_' + parent.val()).remove();

    }

    $(function(){
        cascadeForm = $('.cascadeTest');
        sizSelect = cascadeForm.find('.sizSelect');
        amtSelect = cascadeForm.find('.amtSelect');
        flaSelect = cascadeForm.find('.flaSelect');
        fla2Select = cascadeForm.find('.fla2Select');
        fla3Select = cascadeForm.find('.fla3Select');

        cascadeSelect(sizSelect, amtSelect);
        cascadeSelect(amtSelect, flaSelect);
        cascadeSelect(amtSelect, fla2Select);
        cascadeSelect(amtSelect, fla3Select);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please define how the url should be formed.
F.E. {url}/[flavour_one]/[flavour_two]

For the above example this code should be working:

```
function cascadeSelect(parent, child){
            var childOptions = child.find('option:not(.static)');
                child.data('options',childOptions);

            parent.change(function(){
                $('#'+parent.data('url_param')).text('/'+$(this).val());
                childOptions.remove();
                child
                    .append(child.data('options').filter('.sub_' + this.value))
                    .change(function(){
                        if($(this).val() != 0){
                            $('#'+child.data('url_param')).text('/'+$(this).val());
                        }
                    })
                    .change();
            })

            childOptions.not('.static, .sub_' + parent.val()).remove();
    }
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/lacrioque/wbq8qs82/

Comment: This actually could work!! Now my only concern is that if I pick 3 Flavors and I have my selection made but then I decide to change my mind and go back to 1 Flavor the url doesnt change back it keeps the values that were chosen first.

Comment: Also is there a way to put that div in a button ?

Comment: You want to hire me? :D

Comment: I've updated the fiddle i think you will be able to fiddle the rest out.

Comment: Hey I looked at the fiddle but it still the same as before. Or is there a different link ?

Comment: It is an updated fiddle therefore it has a /1 or in this case /2 at the end. But i have set the base again. so try out. I had to update the chosen jQuery Version and I would heavily recommend using the chosen version .  http://jsfiddle.net/lacrioque/wbq8qs82